# Promotions applied direct on the products catalog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I need to apply promotions direct on the product catalog, is there any way to do it?

By that I mean:

- Creating a promotion on spree Admin.
- The promotion is applied on the product price that is displayed on the product catalog, obviously respecting all the rules on it.
- It should still work on cart as it already work.

Is it possible?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: That's a rather sketchy problem statement, so I think you're unlikely to get any useful answers under the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you want is not so much "promotions" but "sales prices". Which is a little different from how promotions work.

[Spree-sales](https://github.com/ronzalo/spree_sales) is an extension that adds a tab to the product-editing page, where you can add a per-product-per-variant sales price.

Comment: I don't want a  sales_price, I really want a promotion. So i can apply custom rules and actions to it, just like it does on the checkout.

Comment: @renews: in that case I'd advice you to reword the question, because it seems confusing and unclear.